# Get duplicated values from an array by checking with two element

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

If My array have this below data

```
let array = [{ name: "Ramesh", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },
        { name: "Suresh", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 13 },
        { name: "Siva", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 14 },
        { name: "Sakthi", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },...]
```

Then I am expecting this below result

```
[{ name: "Ramesh", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },
 { name: "Sakthi", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 }]
```

---

If My array have this below data

```
let array = [{ name: "Ramesh", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },
        { name: "Suresh", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 14},
        { name: "Siva", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 14 },
        { name: "Sakthi", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },...]
```

Then I am expecting this below result.

```
        [{ name: "Ramesh", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },
        { name: "Sakthi", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 }
        { name: "Suresh", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 14},
        { name: "Siva", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 14 }]
```

I have tried this  way  : [Get all non-unique values (i.e.: duplicate/more than one occurrence) in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/get-all-non-unique-values-i-e-duplicate-more-than-one-occurrence-in-an-array)

```js
let arr = [{ name: "Ramesh", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },
        { name: "Suresh", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 13 },
        { name: "Siva", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 14 },
        { name: "Sakthi", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 }]


var sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort();
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1].SalesVersion == sorted_arr[i].SalesVersion && sorted_arr[i + 1].MarketingCode == sorted_arr[i].MarketingCode) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

But unable to get the duplicated values. Could you please resolve this?

> **Note:** Please mind it should be work as well if the `SalseVersion` and  `MarketingCode` value is `string/number/Boolean`.

because I have tried some of the below answers and i am getting this below error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to find elements for which there exists at least one other element in the array with similar properties. You can use `.filter` for this, followed by `sort`:

```js
const dupesFromArr = array => {
  const filteredArr = array.filter(({ name, SalseVersion, MarketingCode }, i, arr) => (
    arr.find((item, findI) => (
      findI !== i &&
      SalseVersion === item.SalseVersion &&
      MarketingCode === item.MarketingCode
    ))
  ));
  return filteredArr.sort((a, b) =>
    String(a.SalseVersion).localeCompare(String(b.SalseVersion), 'kn') ||
    String(a.MarketingCode).localeCompare(String(b.MarketingCode), 'kn')
  );
};

console.log(dupesFromArr([{name:"Ramesh",SalseVersion:10,MarketingCode:11},{name:"Suresh",SalseVersion:12,MarketingCode:13},{name:"Siva",SalseVersion:10,MarketingCode:14},{name:"Sakthi",SalseVersion:10,MarketingCode:11}]))
console.log(dupesFromArr([{name:"Ramesh",SalseVersion:10,MarketingCode:11},{name:"Suresh",SalseVersion:12,MarketingCode:14},{name:"Siva",SalseVersion:12,MarketingCode:14},{name:"Sakthi",SalseVersion:10,MarketingCode:11}]))
```

Comment: I am getting an error in `filteredArr.sort((a, b) => b.SalesVersion - a.SalesVersion || b.MarketingCode - a.MarketingCode);`  *the left-hand side of an assignment must be variable any int or enum* because the `SalesVersion` property type is string.

Comment: yes I have copied it correctly. But typescript does not allow that

Comment: Your editor is telling you that MarketingCode properties are `string`, but the code you posted shows that they're integers. Something doesn't add up here.

Comment: @RameshRajendran, you can force result using `+` operator. Something like this: `return filteredArr.sort((a, b) => +a.SalseVersion - (+b.SalseVersion) || +a.MarketingCode - (+b.MarketingCode));`

Comment: @Mihai If `MarketingCode` were a `string`, then `+Marketing` would be `NaN`.

Comment: @RameshRajendran Edited to show a solution that converts the items to strings and uses `localeCompare`

Comment: `.1` That make sense :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `reduce`

The first `reduce` will group the values using the concatenated values of `SalseVersion` and `MarketingCode`.

The second `reduce` will check if the group has more than 1 element. If there is `concat` the values into 1 array.

```js
let array = [{ name: "Ramesh", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },{ name: "Suresh", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 14},{ name: "Siva", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 14 },{ name: "Sakthi", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 }];

let result = Object.values(array.reduce((c, v) => {
  let k = v.SalseVersion + '-' + v.MarketingCode;
  c[k] = c[k] || [];
  c[k].push(v);
  return c;
}, {})).reduce((c, v) => v.length > 1 ? c.concat(v) : c, []);

console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code to following

```js
let arr = [{ name: "Ramesh", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },
    { name: "Suresh", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 14},
    { name: "Siva", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 14 },
    { name: "Sakthi", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 },
    { name: "OP", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 }]

// You need to write the custom sort function
var sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort((a,b) => {
     if(a.SalseVersion === b.SalseVersion) {
          return a.MarketingCode- b.MarketingCode;
      }
      return a.SalseVersion - b.SalseVersion;
});
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1].SalesVersion == sorted_arr[i].SalesVersion && sorted_arr[i + 1].MarketingCode == sorted_arr[i].MarketingCode) {
        /* push both the elements in case of match with only exception 
         * being if it has been pushed previously where there are more than 2 matches */
       if (i >= 1 && sorted_arr[i - 1].SalesVersion == sorted_arr[i].SalesVersion && sorted_arr[i - 1].MarketingCode == sorted_arr[i].MarketingCode) {
         results.push(sorted_arr[i+1]);
       } else {
         results.push(sorted_arr[i], sorted_arr[i+1]);
       }            
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically cou could keep sorting, but with the wanted key, this returns a kind of grouped array, where all wanted keys and their values ar in direct neighbourhood.

Then you could filter the array by checking all keys with the actual value and the predecessor or the successor.

```js
var array = [{ name: "Ramesh", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 }, { name: "Suresh", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 13 }, { name: "Siva", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 14 }, { name: "Sakthi", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 }],
    keys = ['SalseVersion', 'MarketingCode'],
    result = array
        .sort((a, b) => {
            var d;
            keys.some(k => d = a[k] - b[k]);
            return d;
        })
        .filter((o, i, a) => 
            keys.every(k => a[i - 1] && a[i - 1][k] === o[k]) ||
            keys.every(k => a[i + 1] && o[k] === a[i + 1][k])
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A single loop approach for unsorted data by using a hash table for temporary collecting the first object of a group or just to indicate duplicates of the group.

```js
var array = [{ name: "Ramesh", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 }, { name: "Suresh", SalseVersion: 12, MarketingCode: 13 }, { name: "Siva", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 14 }, { name: "Sakthi", SalseVersion: 10, MarketingCode: 11 }],
    keys = ['SalseVersion', 'MarketingCode'],
    result = array.reduce((hash => (r, o) => {
        var key = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        if (key in hash) {
            if (hash[key]) {
                r.push(hash[key]);
                hash[key] = false;
            }
            r.push(o);
        } else {
             hash[key] = o;
        }
        return r;
    })(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```